# How do I compute the relative risk aversion of Epstein-Zin preferences?

Tags: utility, risk-aversion

$$
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
$$

## Preface

This question is related to [this one about the elasticity of intertemporal substitution](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/calculate-the-elasticity-of-substitution-of-epstein-zin-preferences/9297#9297) and [this one about the definition of absolute risk aversion](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/definition-of-absolute-risk-aversion). (It's related to the second one insofar as the definition of relative risk aversion can be motivated by the quantity that solves
$$
U(C(1-RRA/2)) = \E[U(C(1-\epsilon))\mid C].
$$

## Question

In this question, I want to know how to compute the *relative risk aversion*
of Epstein-Zin preferences.

Let a consumption
sequence be given $C=(C_0, C_1,...)$ and let
$C_t^+ = (C_t, C_{t+1}, ...)$.
Now, suppose I have Epstein-Zin preferences,
\begin{align*}
U_t(C_t^+) &= f(C_t, q(U_{t+1}(C_{t+1}^+))) \\
U_t  &= \left \{(1-\beta) C_t^{1-\rho} 
+ \beta \left(\E_t[U_{t+1}^{1-\gamma}]\right)^{\frac{1-\rho}{1-\gamma}}
\right\}^{\frac{1}{1-\rho}},
\end{align*}
where $f$ is the time aggregator and $q$ is the conditional certainty
equivalent operator. That is,
$$
f(c,q) = ((1-\beta) c^{1-\rho} + \beta q^{1-\rho})^{\frac{1}{1-\rho}}
$$
and
$$
q_t = q(U_{t+1}) = \left(\E_t[U_{t+1}^{1-\gamma}]\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\gamma}}.
$$
How do I show that the coefficient of relative risk aversion is
$\gamma$?

## Notes

Applying the usual definition of relative risk aversion appears to require care. If we were to calculate $RRA = -c u''(c)/u'(c)$, we would need to be careful
about the time subscripts on $c$. Calculating these derivatives with respect to $C_t$ would not give us the correct answer. It should probably be
$$
RRA = - C_{t+1} \left . \frac{\partial^2 U_t}{\partial C_{t+1}^2} \middle / \frac{\partial U_t}{\partial C_{t+1}} \right. .
$$

Comment: Note that $\gamma$ only "keeps track" of risk aversion, in the sense that $U^1$ is more risk averse than $U^2$ if and only if $\gamma_1>\gamma_2$. But $\gamma$ is not strictly speaking equal to risk aversion. The RRA coefficient is more complicated and depends on $\rho$. I don't have a proof right now, but maybe looking at the Epstein and Zin (1989) paper may help... though it is not a paper that I would qualify as "simple" ;) But if you find something I'd be interested too.

Comment: Actually after quickly looking at the Epstein and Zin's paper, they do not seem to compute the Arrow-Pratt risk aversion coefficients, it may not even exist in closed-form...